# GitLab: use `extends` in `variables`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm wondering if using `extends:` in global `variables:` is supposed to work.

The documentation [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) states, that:

> Keyword type: Job keyword. You can use it **ONLY** as part of a job.

(my highlighting).

However, if I use something like

```yaml
stages:
  - test

.common_variables:
    __FOO: "foo"

variables:
    extends: .common_variables
    __BAR: "bar"

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - env
    rules:
        - when: always
```

then I find both `__FOO` as well as `__BAR` variables defined on the runner. However, I also find the `extends` variable (set to `.common_variables` defined on the runner).

So I wonder if this is the expected behaviour on which one can rely and the presence of `extends` variable is just a minor side effect or just a bug in the GitLab version that we use and this keyword is supported only inside jobs as the docs state?

P.S. note, that i specifically ask about `extends` because i plan to off-load the shared variables into a separate file in a separate repo to be able to reuse it in pipelines of multiple repositories

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works like that.

But you can also read in addition how it can be used correctly if you want to run several scripts in one YAML file.

You can read more details [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: YAML anchors are great, but a the end I want to be able to off-load such templates to be shared by multiple repositories. And anchors do not work for files that are `include`d