# GitLab: extend `!reference` with extra values in `variables`

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can one use `!reference` in `variables` block and then extend the list of entries?

For example, I want to be able to do something like

```yaml
variables:
  !reference [.common_variables, variables]
  FOO: "bar"
```

At the moment I get an error in the GitLab linter:

> This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 1

P.S. Note that this question is specifically about `!reference`.

- Yaml anchors are out of scope of this question, as I want to place `.common_variables` into a separate file that I include in my pipeline.
- `extends:` mechanism is out of scope of this question. It does work, but it has a weird behaviour that one also gets an `extends` variable in the environment, see [GitLab: use `extends` in `variables`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70495596/9640384)

Answer (score 5):

```
variables: !reference [.common_variables, variables]
```

Is the correct way to reference, however gitlab yml structure will not support additional definitions after the !reference keyword.

My advice would be to have a more specific definition in your variables file that uses anchors to share the common varaibles.

e.g:

in 'variables.gitlab-ci.yml':

```
.common_variables: &common_variables
     COMMON_VAR: value

.variables:Example-job
    variables:
        <<: *common_variables
        FOO: "bar"
```

in '.gitlab.ci.yml':

```
Example-job:
    variables: !reference [".variables:Example-job", "variables"]
    script:
        ...
```

Comment: sad that it is the only way... The downside is that i want to place `.common_variables` in a separate "template" repository to be shared between several "application" projects. And thus i can not place `.variables:Example-job` in the same file as `.common_variables` because for any change of "application"-specific variables one will need to change the shared "template"

Comment: with that being the case, you MAY be able to `!reference ['.common_variables', 'variables']` from the external template into `.internal_common_variables` in the 'variables.gitlab-ci.yml', then use the anchor `<<:` to pull those into the `.variables:Example-job`. Not sure if this would work, but might be worth a shot.

Comment: Nice idea. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I achieve it by [using multiple `extends`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#merge-details), one of them, `.contract-env-vars-default`, containing my shared variables.

```yaml
# base template
.contract-env-vars-default:
  variables:
    GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    PACT_BROKER_CLI: ./pact/bin/pact-broker
    …
```

Then using two extends

```yaml
# adding language specific variable
.contract-verify-java:
  extends:
    - .gradle-test-base
    - .contract-env-vars-default # < < < < < < < <
  variables:
    ENVIRONMENT: contract-test # adding language specific variable
```

And finally

```yaml
# adding project specific variable
gradle-contract-testing-verify:
  extends: .contract-verify-java
  variables:
    PROJECT_SPECIFIC: foo_bar_biz # add project specific
```

Thus I got the expected result of:

```yaml
gradle-contract-testing-verify:
  variables:
    CACHE_FALLBACK_KEY: main-cache-non_protected # platform?
    GIT_CURRENT_BRANCH: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" # base
    PACT_BROKER_CLI: "./pact/bin/pact-broker" # base
    …
    ENVIRONMENT: contract-test # language specific
    PROJECT_SPECIFIC: foo_bar_biz # project specific
```

Answer (score -3):

```yaml
variables:
  !reference [.common_variables, variables]
  FOO: "bar"
```

or if you want to assign the variables to a new variable, you can use this

```yaml
variables:
    MY_VAR: !reference [.common_variables, variables]
```

For additional information - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

Comment: See the original question which explicitly states that GitLab complains about the first method and the second allows to configure individual values, but not to insert a block of variables